# Smarty Capitalize throws error: Deprecated: preg_replace(): The /e modifier

Tags: php, smarty

capitalize modifier in smarty throws error

```
{$payment.first_name|capitalize}
```

The above code throws the following error

> Deprecated: preg_replace(): The /e modifier is deprecated, use
>   preg_replace_callback instead in
>   /home/mysuite/public_html/Demo/yoursite/includes/smarty/libs/plugins/modifier.capitalize.php
>   on line 65

Comment: Is there any reason for downvote? unneccessary downvote prevents other users from answering my question.

Comment: Edited my answer to fit your need.

Comment: https://github.com/smarty-php/smarty/issues/80

Answer (score 1):

You can use the php function [ucwords](http://php.net/ucwords) like this.

```
 {$payment.first_name|ucwords}
```

It might not work for non latin characters (not working on cyrillic) but than you can use some library and define your new function as smarty function.